# How do you add multiple colors to one object

Tags: materials, faces

I was trying to create a mug where the outside is one solid color and the inside is the color of the drink. I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) which said I just needed to go into edit mode and select the faces I wanted for color 1 and click assign and do the same for color 2. But whenever I try this my entire object becomes the new color.

How do I get only certain faces to change color?

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you [edit] it and show screenshots of what does mug mesh actually looks like (include viewport and Properties editor with Modifier stack there). If faces of all the object change color when you assign only some of them then probably other faces are generated by modifier, e.g. Solidify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! Good question! This is so easy, that it should probably be used a lot more than it is on objects.

I assume you know how to create the color materials for objects, so I won't address that. Every time you go to the materials tab to make a new material, you click the "+" or "Add" button. You can do that many times. So, go ahead and create the materials you need.

BTW, the method I describe here is SO simple, but, the best way is to absolutely UV edit. Whew! What a chore. I prefer this stupid simple method.

What you do next is simply go into "Edit Object" mode, and use the "face" selection. Select the faces you want of the particular material. Select the proper material from the list of materials I advised you to create above, and click that "Assign" button. Select the faces you want of a different material, and, from that same list of materials, "Assign" the appropriate material to those faces. Stupid simple, no?

[image: Assign material to selected faces]
[image: Three materials - One object]